# Set record property when creating instance

Tags: f#

I have a record type

```ml
type Record = { Start: DateTime; End: DateTime; Duration: TimeSpan }
let record = { Start = DateTime.Now; End = DateTime(2021,12,1) }
```

This code won't compile as there's no assignment given for field `Duration`.

Is it possible to calculate `Duration` in the type definition instead of assigning it?

Answer (score 5):

Solved it:

```ml
type Record = { Start: DateTime; End: DateTime; }
with
  member this.Duration = this.End - this.Start

let record = { Start = DateTime.Now; End = DateTime(2021,12,1) }
```

Comment: This works, but note that it will recalculate `Duration` every time it's called.

Comment: @brianberns Thanks. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I'll write a separate answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to recompute `Duration` every time it's called, you can do something like this:

```ml
type Record = private { Start: DateTime; End: DateTime; Duration: TimeSpan }

let create startTime endTime =
    {
        Start = startTime
        End = endTime
        Duration = endTime - startTime
    }

let record = create DateTime.Now (DateTime(2021,12,1))
```

Note that I've made the fields `private`, so users will be forced to call `create`. The only downside of this approach is that users can no longer access the fields at all, so you might want to provide separate accessors for them:

```ml
type Record = private { _Start: DateTime; _End: DateTime; _Duration: TimeSpan } with
    member this.Start = this._Start
    member this.End = this._End
    member this.Duration = this._Duration

let create startTime endTime =
    {
        _Start = startTime
        _End = endTime
        _Duration = endTime - startTime
    }

let record = create DateTime.Now (DateTime(2021,12,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

This too will not recalculate Duration. It's not a record though.

```
type MyClass(startTime, endTime) =
    member val Start: DateTime = startTime
    member val End: DateTime = endTime
    member val Duration: TimeSpan = endTime - startTime

let myObject = MyClass(DateTime.Now, DateTime(2021,12,1))
```

But I wouldn't go to this much trouble just to avoid the recalculation, unless it was time critical. That goes for the other answers too.